# How can I find which http (not https) requests my Android app is making and know the domain they are of the request?

Tags: android, android-networking

My app is required to have the `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` attribute, which is a problem because some third party libraries think that means they can use `http` instead of `https`.

I've implemented `detectCleartextNetwork` on `StrictMode` but when that gets triggered I only get the IP address, I don't get the domain name.

Android Studio under the network inspector shows me all calls with the URL and everything. Is there a way I can get that programmatically?

I know I can add a `interceptor` to `okhttp` for my own calls but what I need to find is calls from third party libraries that might not be using `https`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: May be better use a NetworkSecurityConfig.xml file and permit clear text http only to specific domains you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately my app has to talk to devices on the local network and I don't know which IPs they'll be at.